# mkdir() not working in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, mkdir

I am working in PHP, I have tried to create a directory based on `package_id`. This is the code that I tried to execute

```
$path=$this->BASE_URL."assets/public/package/".$package_id;

                if (!is_dir($path)) 
                {
                    mkdir($path,'0777', true);
                }
```

Comment: And....? Check error logs.

Comment: @Mike, output is bool(false)

Comment: @raheez That means it's not being created. Check the error logs as marekful suggests.

Comment: What is the value of `$path`? Do you have rights to create directories in that  path? Is `$path` an existing file?

Comment: Any reason for the un-acceptance of my answer?

Comment: @apache's answer is correct that's because when I used local host path it doesn't work when I changed without local host path its worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code

```
 $path='./assets/public/package/'.$package_id;
 if (!is_dir($path))                             
 {
   mkdir($path,'0777', true);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **absolute** path :

```
   $path= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/assets/public/package/".$package_id;

    if (!is_dir($path))                             
               {
                   mkdir($path,'0777', true);
               }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using FCPATH

```
$path = FCPATH . "assets/public/package/". $package_id;

if (!is_dir($path)) 
{
   mkdir($path,'0777', true);

   // @mkdir($path,'0777', true);
}
```